# Access html form element, inside iframe without id/name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have the following code-structure (nested HTMLs, although that probably doesn't make much of a difference)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe>
            <html>
                <form id="loginForm" name ="loginFormName">
                    <input id ="name" name ="username">
                    </input>
                </form>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html
```

I tried it by accessing the input field via:

```
document.getElementById("name");
document.loginFormName.username;
```

But I believe the iFrame hinders me to access the elements. However, somehow accessing the iFrame first:

`document.getElementByTagName("iframe).getElementById("name");`

does not yield any results other than "undefined".

Help is much appreciated, I would like to auto-set the value of the input field and auto-submit the form. (form.submit). I have no preference regarding Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: document.getElementById("name").value() try this because you want get the value from the input field

Comment: yes, I know, that eventually I will need .value. The problem is that I cannot access the object in the first place.

Comment: Since you are using a third party for the source of the iframe, can you post exact code you're working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) for that.

> The contents( ) method finds all the child nodes inside the matched elements (including text nodes), or the content document, if the element is an iframe.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('input')
```

If you want to submit the form, you can use this.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('form').submit();
```

Sample [**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/dWpvf/1942/) to show how content in an iframe is accessed by `contents( )`.

Comment: did you ran that in the console? Be sure to run that after iframe loads

Comment: Hi @RinoRaj.  
Thank you for the demo and the JQuery. In my case there are multiple input fields, so I first wanted to see, if the Query returns anything:   
    `var counter = $('iframe').contents().find('input'); `  
But   
   ` counter.length `  
displays to be 0? Is .length not applicable here?
Would I access the first input field found then via:  
` $('iframe').contents().find('input')[0];?`

Comment: I displayed the counter on the website as a element.innerHTML= counter.length

The iframe loads through a JS API, but my code is at the very bottom of the page, right before </body>.

Comment: I now even switched it to call the code as an "onload" event of the iframe, yet the result has not changed unfortunately.

Comment: @seulberg1 I am not sure about the cause. It is working fine in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing an element of an iframe is very easy.

You should use the following syntax for access input element & form submit:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('input'); //Form Element access

$('iframe').contents().find('#loginForm').submit(); //Form submit code
```

Hope it helps to resolve your query!

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe is in the same domain as your parent page you can access the elements using document.frames collection.

give any id to your iFrame and replace myIFrame with your iFrame id

**window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('name')**

If your iframe is not in the same domain the browser should prevent such access for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are loading your iframe incorrectly.

```html
  <div class="main">
    <iframe src="iframecontent.html">
    </iframe>
  </div>


  <!--iframecontent.html :-->

  <html>
  <body>
      <form id="loginForm" name ="loginFormName">
          <input id ="name" name ="username">
          </input>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: and then do `var counter = $('iframe').contents().find('input'); `
and log out counter.length

Comment: i reduced the simplicity of the sytax too much in my example. The iframe is called exactely that way, but then again the iFrame itself is from a third-party API, hence I cannot change its structure.

The above mentioned JQuery unfortunately still doesnt yield anything.